# Binding functions (`exec`uted at runtime) to a module (created at runtime)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am developing an application that uses a "runtime generated module". The fashion is the following:

```
import imp
import sys

a_module = imp.new_module("runtime_module")
sys.modules["runtime_module"] = a_module
```

For a simplified two-function example, I have them stored in two different `txt` files. I should read from file, but to make it more simple:

```
# First function
source_func1 = """def func1_implementation():
    func2()
"""

# Second function
source_func2 = """def func2_implementation():
    pass
"""
```

And, to "populate" the class, I load the code into `source_func1` and source_func2` and do the following:

```
exec compile(source_func1, "__remote__func1__", "exec")
exec compile(source_func2, "__remote__func2__", "exec")
a_module.func1 = func1_implementation
a_module.func2 = func2_implementation
```

I would like to be able to do the following:

```
import runtime_module
runtime_module.func1()
```

However...

```
----------------------
NameError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-4a304d14319a> in <module>()
      1 import runtime_module
----> 2 runtime_module.func1()

/.../__remote__func1__ in func1_implementation()

NameError: global name 'func2' is not defined
```

How can I manage the namespace? Is there a pythonic way to achieve what I am trying to do? I don't have a lot of freedom on the `txt` files (from which I execute the source file). I also don't fully understand "where" are the namespaces/locals/globals, so maybe I am overlooking some easy solution.

Comment: Do you really need to use Python 2.7? Because a lot of what you want to do is a whole lot easier in 3.4—and even the stuff that isn't easier is better documented…

Comment: Unfortunately yes... I added the tag 2.7 because of it. What I am developing is intended to be for a certain 2.7-only library --and migrating that is not on the table :(

Comment: OK, there seem to be some pretty basic misunderstandings here that we have to get past first. Did you expect `setattr(a_module, "func1", locals()["func1_implementation"])` to do something different than just `a_module.func1 = func1_implementation`? If so, what?

Comment: No, I expected exactly that. What I expected is that if `a_module.func2 = <something>` then the namespace would be automagically "updated". And that doesn't happen, `func2` is not defined :(

Comment: When you write `a_module.func2 = <something>`, that just compiles into `setattr(a_module, "func2", something)`. So writing the latter explicitly is never going to fix anything. And likewise, using `locals()["func1_implementation"]` is never going to give you anything better than `func1_implementation` (unless you're inside a function, and you explicitly want an exception if it's global rather than local).

Comment: Sorry, that was a misdirection. I know. I added an edit but it may be more readable to change the code, let me edit it into something simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that when you execute a function definition, it binds the global environment at that time to its `__globals__` attribute, and when the function is later called, that's what's used as the frame's globals.

So, you can look at `func1_implementation.__globals__`, and it's obviously your module's globals, not `a_module`'s globals.

You can solve this just by doing:

```
exec compile(source_func1, "__remote__func1__", "exec") in a_module.__dict__
exec compile(source_func2, "__remote__func2__", "exec") in a_module.__dict__

a_module.func1 = a_module.func1_implementation
a_module.func2 = a_module.func2_implementation
```

Those last two lines replace the `setattr(…)` bit, which is just obfuscating the same thing. `a_module.func1 = <something>` is the same thing as `setattr(a_module, "func1", <something>)`, and `locals()["func1_implementation"]` is the same thing as `func1_implementation`.

---

Notice that this puts `func1_implementation` into `a_module`. Which isn't as bad as putting it into your own top-level module, but it's still not great.

You can solve that in a number of ways: just extract the `code` objects and use `types.FunctionType` to construct new `function` objects bound to the right namespace, use a new namespace and cram it into `a_module` after the fact, or, probably simplest, just this:

```
del a_module.func1_implementation
del a_module.func2_implementation
```

This is, after all, the same thing you do in normal modules when you need a helper function to build a class or something but don't want to keep it around in the module after it's built…